# ffmpeg: Set "year" metadata equal to first 4 characters of another metadata variable (flac)

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

The flac files I am dealing with has an attributed named "Date released", whose value is in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".

Is it possible for me to take the "YYYY" from this and set the year variable equal to it?

```
    ffmpeg -i input.flac -metadata year=??? -codec copy output.flac
```

---

Bonus question, is it possible to do this in place without creating a new file? Or would I have to create a new file and then delete the old one?

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't believe there is any option for ffmpeg to edit a file in place.  It always creates a new file.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to do this in multiple steps.

1. Get the metadata with `ffprobe`:

   ```
   ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries format_tags="Date released" -of csv=p=0 input.flac
   ```

   Results in something like 2001-12-16.
2. Process output to get year. Your OS/shell/scripting/coding language is unknown so I'll leave that part up to you.
3. Add the metadata:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input.flac -c copy -metadata year=2001 output.flac
   ```

> Bonus question, is it possible to do this in place without creating a new file?

Not possible with `ffmpeg`.

> Or would I have to create a new file and then delete the old one?

Yes.